# What does M ↓ mean in a Python notebook?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

See the `M ↓` in the screenshot below. What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: Probably Markdown

Comment: Thanks although that cell has Python code and not markdown, right? @tehhowch